# High pitched noise as hot object hits water?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qSEfcIfYbw

Just wondering what this phenomenon was called, and its cause? Would have googled, but I don't even know what it's called.

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38588/why-is-there-a-hiss-sound-when-water-falls-on-a-hot-surface?rq=1), surely could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the boiling of water, with the high rate of volumetric expansion producing a vibration in the air, thus producing sound. You can see that the sound is most evident when the nickel ball is in direct contact with the water, as the thermal conduction is greatest and thus water boils fastest when in direct contact. There is also a period of time during which the sound produced is of a lower frequency and amplitude, which is when there seems to be a bubble around the nickel ball. The bubble provides an insulation between the nickel ball and the water, thus slowing down the boiling of water in another phenomenon known as the Leidenfrost effect.